# Hide and close a hidden div

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden fixed div and want to display it if I click on a btn, and close if I click on any where else. Right now, I can hide the div if I click on a button or any where on the page.

For the code below, I have achieve half of what I want. However, I want to the div still open (visible) if I click on any where in the green box. Can anyone suggest any idea to help me achieve that?

```js
$(function() {
 var OPEN = 0;   /* Offset to Open */
 var CLOSE = -10000;  /* Offset to Close */

 var t = 0;        /* Default time */
 var $obtn = $(".obtn-side");
 var $cbtn = $(".cbtn-side");
 var main = ".main-wrapper";

 $obtn.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var cid = $(this).attr("href"); /* Get the container id */
  navEffect(cid, OPEN, 0);
 });


 $cbtn.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var cid = $(this).attr("href");

  navEffect(cid, CLOSE, 0);
 });

 $(".side-wrapper").click(function(event) {
   navEffect("#side", CLOSE, 0);

 });

});

function navEffect(c, o, t) {
 var $con = $(c);
 $con.animate({
  right: o
 }, t);
}
```

```css
.side-wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: black;
 right: -1100%;
}

.side-container {
 float: right;
 background: green;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative; 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.9);
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="side" class="side-wrapper">
 <div class="side-container">
  <a class="cbtn-side" href="#side">x</a>
        <div>
          <h1>Side bar</h1>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>

<a class="obtn-side" href="#side">open</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop event bubbling in case of the click on the green area `.side-container`:

```
$(".side-container").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
$(function() {
 var OPEN = 0;   /* Offset to Open */
 var CLOSE = -10000;  /* Offset to Close */

 var t = 0;        /* Default time */
 var $obtn = $(".obtn-side");
 var $cbtn = $(".cbtn-side");
 var main = ".main-wrapper";

 $obtn.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var cid = $(this).attr("href"); /* Get the container id */
  navEffect(cid, OPEN, 0);
 });


 $cbtn.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var cid = $(this).attr("href");

  navEffect(cid, CLOSE, 0);
 });

 $(".side-wrapper").click(function(event) {
   navEffect("#side", CLOSE, 0);

 });
  
    $(".side-container").click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

});

function navEffect(c, o, t) {
 var $con = $(c);
 $con.animate({
  right: o
 }, t);
}
```

```css
.side-wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: black;
 right: -1100%;
}

.side-container {
 float: right;
 background: green;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative; 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.9);
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="side" class="side-wrapper">
 <div class="side-container">
  <a class="cbtn-side" href="#side">x</a>
        <div>
          <h1>Side bar</h1>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>

<a class="obtn-side" href="#side">open</a>
```